Jquery and Jquery UI update
i have Jquery 1.9.1 version and Jquery UI 1.10.3 and Require.js 2.1.5 in our currect project.
i want update this file into our project i just replace those files into latest files like Jquery 3.7.1 and Jquery UI 1.13.3 and Require.js 2.3.6 versions after updating iam getting like below.

TypeError: progressbar.progressbar is not a function

TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(V){"use strict";V.ui=V.ui||{};V.ui.version="1.13.3";var

Syntax error unrecognized expression #...


Can anyone please help me to resolve those issues.
I try to replace what ever that files related i replace those and after replacing iam getting error like above.
